# Selenium Java Chrome remove flag

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, automation, driver

I want to hide that I use a Webdriver. I know the needed Code for Python:

```
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

but I want it for Java. I tried this but I get errors:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']);
options.setExperimentalOption('useAutomationExtension', False);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("");
```

I hope you can help me out.

Best Regards

Christian

Comment: was there an error (`false` would be lowercase java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java it will be

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```